# Golang Gorilla Websocket Client Test Cases

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I just implemented the Websocket in Golang using Gorilla Toolkit. How I can write the test cases for WebSocket Server and Client. The client and server code is available for reference in [Github](https://github.com/Fu-XDU/gorilla-websocket-example) . I just want to write the test cases for server and client side.

```html
var addr = flag.String("addr", "localhost:8080", "http service address")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(0)

    interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

    u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: *addr, Path: "/echo"}
    log.Printf("connecting to %s", u.String())

    c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dial:", err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    done := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        for {
            _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("read:", err)
                return
            }
            log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
        }
    }()

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            return
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(t.String()))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("write:", err)
                return
            }
        case <-interrupt:
            log.Println("interrupt")

            err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, ""))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("write close:", err)
                return
            }
            select {
            case <-done:
            case <-time.After(time.Second):
            }
            return
        }
    }
}
```